# Should Static Values go in a Table, or should I create a Case Statment

Tags: sql-server, performance, case

I am writing code where I can create a table with 41 rows and do a join or I can create a case statement

the table would look something like this:

```
minValue,MaxValue,Category,Tier; 
876,999,a,5; 
826,875,a,6; 
801,825,b,7; 
776,800,c,8;
```

and I would do a join that looks like this

```
Update results
set answer = tier
from results a
left outer join  lookuptable b on a.value>= b.minValue and a.value <=b.MaxValue
and a.Catagory = b.catagory
```

if I did a case statement it would look like this

```
Update results
set answer = case cat when a then  
case when value>=876 and value<=999 then 5
case when value>=826 and value<=875 then 6
case when value>=801 and value<=825 then 7
... end
when b then 
case when value>=876 and value<=999 then 7
case when value>=826 and value<=875 then 8
case when value>=801 and value<=825 then 12
... end... end
```

so I would end up with a really large nested case statement.  the results table can have up to 500,000 rows.  what is the most efficient?

Comment: I would go with a Lookup table.  Limit the changes to one place leaving the query alone. Also the query would be smaller and easier to read and maintain

Comment: Definitely a table. And if possible change the column name so it is spelled category. :)